# After a successful install, my screen blinks indefinitely

Tags: drivers, graphics, screen, radeon

I have been here in the past to ask this same question, I've been having issues with it for months and months, and months now - any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Essentially when I install Ubuntu - of any sort - it successfully installs but than the Radeon graphics card driver apparently doesn't work and the screen just turns on and off after boot.  Works great off usb.

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [Radeon HD 6600M/6700M/7600M Series] [1002:6741]
```

Also, worth noting I've tried multiple times to download the newest driver from Radeon site and the .run opens SO slow after 3 hours it was less than 25%, needless to say I quit out of that each time.... I've tried all the drivers I was able to find... and now I am unsure of how to even have these updates effect my actual filesystem on my PC - not just the USB, as I set up a 1.4G persistence.  Lastly it is worth noting that RANDOMLY it will work after the install, meaning, the graphics driver just works, the screen does not blink on and off.  The only reason it doesn't still work is I've had to reinstall due to other issues.

I am not very well versed in these things - but all I want to do is use my computer.  After about 75 days the OS is so buggy I have to reinstall.  But I suppose THAT part is neither here nor there as all I want at the moment is to get this graphics card working.

I don't understand how if I set up a persistence file on my usb of Studio 13 how the changes I make will effect the installed version of Studio on my computers HDD.

I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver and many other pages but none have helped fix my issue

I could REALLY use some help here guys, not finding it in IRC either.  Anything would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the LiveCD/USB work then? If it does, could you replace your current hardware information with the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A4 VGA`? Also, long time problems are more likely to be a bug or a hardware issue, have you tried another Linux distribution or Windows and see this problem? After you have installed your system, if you press Ctrl+Alt+F2 did it brings you to a black screen? If it does please execute the same command in grey above and append the results. Remember to include both differentiated. I presume you should know how to [edit] your question.

Comment: I couldn't track down your previous questions, could you add a link to them?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well on the default open-source drivers got AMD Radeon HD 6670. Installing the Catalyst driver fixed it. I've had to use the recovery mode to install it, though.